# transformation between a landmark and robot?

Tags: localization, navigation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the robots position by detecting a landmark with a laser.
I want to do a localization through laser markers to have another option beside odometry and laser scan matching.
The coordinates of the landmark are known in my base_laser_link frame and in my global map frame.

I tried to manually calculate the transformations, but it only works on paper ;)
When I try it in ROS, I have a correct position only for a few specific orientation angles. When I turn too much, the calculated robot position drifts away.

Could I place a static tf on the map for a landmark? map -> landmark
So ROS does the transformation? Or does this approach take my position estimate into account? So I would need a transformation from landmark -> base_laser_link and not landmark -> map -> base_link -> base_laser_link

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68536/transformation-between-a-landmark-and-robot?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are looking for long term storage recording the position or transform from the map is probably the right thing to do.  For short term interaction you could use the Advanced  tf API with a fixed_frame of "map".

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1